# Plot density curve in R with two density functions

Tags: r, statistics, curve, probability-density

I am struggling to create a continuous density curve in R for the below pdf:

```
{ 3x(1-x)^2     0 < x < 1

f(x) = { 3(2-x)(1-x)^2  1 ≤ x  < 2

{ 0              otherwise
```

Using the curve function, I can plot the two functions separately but not together:

```
curve(3*x*(1-x)^2,0,1)

curve(3*(2-x)*(1-x)^2,1,2)
```

Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start with an *empty* graph and then put together these pieces with `add=TRUE`.

```
plot(NULL, xlim=c(0,2), ylim=c(0,0.5))
curve(3*x*(1-x)^2,0,1, add=TRUE)
curve(3*(2-x)*(1-x)^2,1,2, add=TRUE)
```

[image: Two curves]